# ADFS Skip Home Realm Discovery using integrated auth

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, adfs2.0

My scenario:

I've got a .net web application where people log into the app with forms authentication, and my forms authentication code sends certain users off to ADFS to be verified. I have multiple federations, including my own Active Directory server for internal users. So, for users that need to be sent to ADFS for authentication, I do something like this:

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule instance = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
SignInRequestMessage request = instance.CreateSignInRequest(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), instance.Realm, true);
request.AuthenticationType = "urn:federation:authentication:windows";
//maybe you just don't need to specify the homerealm for ad, because there can only be one AD (integrated) trust?
//request.HomeRealm = "I-no-idea-what-to-put-here-for-AD";
Response.Redirect(request.WriteQueryString());
```

When you do this, you set the .HomeRealm property which populates the whr attribute for you on the query string. This should make AD FS skip the HRD (Home Realm Discovery) page. For most of my federations (remote STSs) it's very clear what value I need to put in the property, you can pull the value from the dropdown box on the HRD page itself, or you can go into the AD FS management tool and pull the value from the trust properties. For the AD trust, however, there is no value in the dropdown list (empty string), and you can't go to properties in the management console. So the question is really this: if I want to preselect the AD trust through the whr parameter, what do I set the HomeRealm Property to?

P.S. you'll see the comment there: "maybe you just don't need to specify the homerealm for ad, because there can only be one AD (integrated) trust?" I think this might be the case, but I haven't proved it yet. I will answer this later if my guess is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code in the original question:

```
    request.AuthenticationType = "urn:federation:authentication:windows";
```

That particular line didn't appear to have any effect. Also, the hope that no HomeRealm need be specified was also in vain. It turns out that you must, in fact, specify the HomeRealm. After searching google for some time, I found many statements hinting that the Active Directory trust was the same as trusting the ADFS server itself. So as a wild shot in the dark I tried putting in the URI of the ADFS server, and, much to my pleasure and surprise, this worked.

So, to be more clear, if you go to the web.config of the relying party you should have something set up similar to this:

```
<issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
  <authority name="http://testadfs.test.com/adfs/services/trust">
    <keys>
      <add thumbprint="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    </keys>
    <validIssuers>
      <add name="http://testadfs.test.com/adfs/services/trust" />
    </validIssuers>
  </authority>
</issuerNameRegistry>
```

I ended up setting the value of request.HomeRealm to the value that you see there in the validIssuers and authority elements. This gave me the desired effect of causing ADFS to automatically select the Active Directory claims provider trust.

I should be clear that my ADFS server is NOT the domain controller, and yet this still works.

Comment: awesome! this just helped me out a lot!